# Microservices database architecture

Tags: spring, cloud, microservices

I have a question about microservice architecture

for example if i have two microservice "UserService" and "TaskService"

and i have the database for my systeme with two table "USER" and "TASK"

We know that one of the Microservices rules is that each Microservice has its own database

So I don't know how to distribute my database for this two microservices ?

1. set for the database for the "UserService" microservice two tables "USER" and "TASK"

and set for the database for the "TaskService" microservice two tables also "USER" and "TASK"

or

2. set for the database for the "UserService" microservice the table "USER"

and set for the database for the "TaskService" microservice the table "TASK" but the problem here is how to link the two tables "USER" and "TASK" because each one is in a different database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question you have to ask yourself is if in this case you really need a microservice architecture. If as you say, the service has only two tables, and the two are closely related (so both will propably belongs to the same bounded context). The most probably answer is no.

Because this way you will add more complexity and latency to the system.

With this in mind, If you really need this architecture, because the real application is more complex and you have identified that this two services belong to different bounded contexts, I mean their functionality are not closely related, the way to solve this is that each microservice owns its own database with its own table.

So the user service will have its own table as well as task service. If there is a use case in user service that needs information of task service or viceversa. You can do a request from origin service to target service to retrieve this information or if you really need to decouple the two and/or you have performance requirements, then the solution could be to have a read only table with the other service information that you need and update it by subscribe to the changes of the table owner using kafka for example or another message broker

Comment: I have given an example just to understand a microservices architecture this is not my real case.
so you mean in the first solution set for each microservices  its own table
but how can i know this task for this user add id_user in task table or what

Comment: exactly, in one of the two services you must store the relation between the two tables. The problem here is the consistency, so for example if a user is deleted the task service must know it, so in this case the better approach is to use a message broker to suscribe the task service to the user events ans update the database accordingly. The problem here is eventual consistency, if you can't assume this or don't want to manage a message broker you can make direct calls between services to maintain coherency but this will couple both services and is less performant

Comment: thank you ,
you mean communication asynchronous but like you say if i delete the user the broker itself communicate the second service for delete task connected with this user
or should I configure the broker for do that

Comment: You should configure the broker with one topic for user events. So every time a user changes or is removed the user service should send an event to this topic indicating the userid and the action done. Then the task service that is listen to this topic will read the event and update its database accordingly

Comment: ok thanks so much
in the second solution set the same database architecture for this two microservices and the broker updates the two database with each other
Which method do you recommend or depending on the case

Comment: In fact it is the same solution. the difference is that in the second case you may store additional info of the other service because you may need it and not only the id. and all the information of the user must be updated when a change occurs.